# How to fetch row from redshift with condition

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned two tables:

table_1

```
ID      Date                   Value
1254    2018-01-01 15:20:45    RT-RF
1254    2018-01-10 18:22:45    RE-RI
1255    2018-01-25 17:35:40    RR-RU
1255    2018-01-30 13:19:55    RY-RR
```

Table_2

```
ID      Date2                  Value2
1254    2018-01-01 08:12:16    RT-RF
1255    2018-01-25 18:14:18    RT-RF
```

How to check for every Unique `ID` the `Value2` in table is not matching with the oldest value1 of that particular `ID` in table in.

Required Output:

```
ID   Date                       Date2               Value    Value2
1255 2018-01-01 15:20:45        2018-01-25 18:14:18 RT-RF    RT-RF
```

Comment: It should be `RR-RU` in the expected output

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

From your Required output, you put the ones that DID match, for that case use this:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Date, t2.Date2,t1.Value,t2.Value from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
where t1.Value = t2.Value2
```